# angular data not binding complete data from model to view

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, mean-stack

Hi i am making a edit profile page for a user, and i am using MEAN stack

saving a fresh user works fine, now for editing the details, I have fetched the saved user from mongodb and this is what i get on the browser console( which is correct)

```
...
firstName: "Syed",
middleName: "",
lastName: "Faizan",
dob: "07/06/2015"
...
```

when i try to map these values to the View, all the data is not getting filled in the View. (i am using the same form that i used to save a fresh user, so logically it should map correctly, but it isn't).

There are other fields too that aren't getting pre- filled( only some, not showing the full json)

and i would have shown the screenshot of the webpage, but it seems i can't attach a image unless i have 10 reputation.

i tried using $scope.$apply() method, no luck.

EDIT: Jade Code for the above

```
form.login-form.form-horizontal(method='post', role='form' name='userForm')
input#fName.form-control(placeholder='Your first name', required, name='fName', type='text', ng-model='UI.student.firstName')
input#mName.form-control(placeholder='Your middle name', name='mName', type='text', ng-model='UI.student.name.middleName')
input#lName.form-control(placeholder='Your last name', required, name='lName', type='text', ng-model='UI.student.name.lastName')
ng-bs3-datepicker#dob(name='dob', ng-model='UI.student.dob', language='en')
....
```

Controller Code:

```
$http.get("/fetchStudentData").success(function(response){
    $scope.UI.student= response;
    console.log(response);

})
```

Comment: Can you provide your html code?

Comment: and controller code...

Comment: sorry for shabby post, i have updated the post.

Comment: There is no $apply $digest problem in $http service

Comment: i don't get any $apply $digest problems, i got that error once i used $scope.$apply(), so i didn't use it